# how do i iterate through object parameters such that certain object parameters are displayed inline in a panel block using bootstrap

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

this is my json data:

```
{
    "roleID": 1,
    "roleName": "Admin",
    "active": true,
    "module": [
        {
            "moduleID": 6,
            "moduleDescription": "Application",
            "pageName": "Application",
            "underModuleID": 0,
            "subModules": [
                {
                    "moduleID": 1,
                    "moduleDescription": "civil bill",
                    "pageName": "civil bill",
                    "underModuleID": 6,
                    "roleModulePermissions": [
                        {
                            "roleModuleAllocationID": 8,
                            "roleID": 1,
                            "moduleID": 1,
                            "moduleRead": true,
                            "moduleWrite": true,
                            "moduleCreate": false
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        }]}
```

i want to  iterate through my object parameters, in the array roleModulePermissions i want to iterate parameters moduleRead,moduleWrite,moduleCreate such that i get a 3 checkbox inside a row which displays the values of this parameters how should i write html script to access the data like i specified.and i want the data to come in bootstrap row panel

Answer (score 0):

You can created nested `table` and achieve this.

Here is the working snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
      app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.roles = {
          "roleID": 1,
          "roleName": "Admin",
          "active": true,
          "module": [{
            "moduleID": 6,
            "moduleDescription": "Application",
            "pageName": "Application",
            "underModuleID": 0,
            "subModules": [{
              "moduleID": 1,
              "moduleDescription": "civil bill",
              "pageName": "civil bill",
              "underModuleID": 6,
              "roleModulePermissions": [{
                "roleModuleAllocationID": 8,
                "roleID": 1,
                "moduleID": 1,
                "moduleRead": true,
                "moduleWrite": true,
                "moduleCreate": false
              }]
            }]
          }]
        };
      }]);
    }());
  </script>


  <style></style>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">

    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Module</th>
        <th>Sub Module</th>
      </tr>>
      <tr ng-repeat="module in roles.module">
        <td col-span="2">{{module.pageName}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="submodule in module.subModules">
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <td>{{submodule.pageName}}</td>
              <td ng-repeat="permission in submodule.roleModulePermissions">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.moduleRead">Read</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.moduleWrite">Write</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.moduleCreate">Create</label>
                  </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```